# How to check CA Root and Intermediate chain?

Tags: ssl, ca

For example - let's take jks which contains **Comodo CA root** cert, few intermediate certs and own server signed cert:

```
 # keytool -list -keystore akira.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 5 entries

comodoutnsgcca, Jan 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): C7:1E:D8:79:91:4C:01:AC:ED:ED:00:30:4C:47:F0:E4
akira, Jan 16, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): A6:90:2D:8A:0E:4B:A3:0A:B5:50:9A:E3:F9:B8:E5:AC
essentialsslca_2, Jan 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B5:1A:6D:2D:44:CC:72:D6:C6:2A:1B:97:5A:18:3D:91
utnaddtrust, Jan 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 55:07:0F:1F:9A:E5:EA:21:61:F3:72:2B:8B:41:7F:27
addtrustexternalcaroot, Jan 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 1D:35:54:04:85:78:B0:3F:42:42:4D:BF:20:73:0A:3F
```

How can I see exactly viewing cert's entry - that it require other cert in chain?

If I run `-list` with `-v` option - I see a lot of info like `"Extensions"`, `"#1: ObjectId"` and so on.

So - which one line there describes the dependencies?

Comment: It's determined by the issuer of each cert in the chain.  Your cert was issued by a specific issuer; that issuer was in turn issued by another, etc. up to a trusted root.  You have to walk the chain of cert to cert.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is an answer:

```
# openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=4 /C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by LeaderTelecom Ltd./OU=Free     SSL/CN=akira.setevoy.kiev.ua
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=EssentialSSL CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=EssentialSSL CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN - DATACorp SGC
 3 s:/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN - DATACorp SGC
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 4 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Here is full chain - from local signed cert (`CN=akira.setevoy.kiev.ua`) till root CA - (`CN=AddTrust External CA Root`).

`s` here is "`subject`" - "name" of cert and `i` is `issuer` - who issued this cert.

So Root have name `AddTrust External CA Root` and it's issued by `AddTrust External CA Root`.

Other way - use online tools like [SSL Checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://rtfm.co.ua:8443).